# How can I prevent or mitigate the front wheel coming off the ground when climbing steep hills?

Tags: technique, climbing, equipment

On one of my bicycles (a 2012 Trek Madone 4.7), when climbing very steep hills, I have had problems with the front wheel coming off the ground. This creates an extremely dangerous situation because when this happens one loses all steering control.

Do I have any recourse beyond choosing a less steep route, getting less fat (catch 22), or using a different bicycle?

Comment: Are you already in the drops when climbing? If not, moving to the drops will bring your center of gravity further forward and down.

Comment: @Kibber: I'm hardly ever in the drops. Will have to see if that'll work.

Comment: How steep is 'very steep'?

Comment: @Glenn: I'm not sure. I don't have any equipment for measuring this. Suffice to say this is the steepest hill I've ever been on :) (Specifically, climbing Denny Way up into Capitol Hill in Seattle)

Comment: When quoting steep slopes like this, its very handy to quote a Strava segment but I can't find one.    Assuming its https://goo.gl/maps/2Ra1E2BSSoP2    then the path of   https://www.strava.com/routes/9005337  is 38 metres elevation over 0.3 km, so its a good 10% and could be as high as 15% for sections of it.   Its full of cars too, so not a fun road to be crawling up on a bike.

Comment: A longer-wheelbase bike can help too, but its not a first resort and could be non-UCI compliant, if that matters to you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Move your weight further forward to keep the front wheel weighted. Shuffle forwards on your seat and bring your chest closer to the bars. Standing can help for the steepest parts, but can cause your rear wheel to slip on loose surfaces.

The front wheel is lifting as when your bike is on a slope the wheelbase is effectively shortened, bringing your weight closer to the rear axle, and the most vertical part of the *wheelie* is already done.

Comment: Indeed, lean extremely forward, while still keeping weight on the seat. Very carefully choose the gear, in which you can pedal smoothly - neither too high nor too low.

Comment: I second the pedaling smoothly approach. Good form saves lots of trouble.

Comment: Indeed -- if a gear was made which would let me pedal this particular hill smoothly that'd probably help a bunch :P

Comment: @BillyONeal don't be afraid to try a bigger range cassette or smaller ring up front, could make the difference while your fitness improves.

Comment: And elbows down.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest that your bike is not set up correctly and your centre of gravity is too far back.

The first thing to consider is what is the predominant terrain you are riding?

1. If its mostly flat consider using a technique such as alex has
   suggested in his answer to cover pinch climbs and small hills.
2. If your doing a lot of climbing (sitting on the front of your seat
   is uncomfortable and more suited to mtb) the second thing is to
   change the set up of your bike to fit you better. One of the biggest
   misconceptions made by bike stores when they set a bike up for
   people seems to be that they believe the rider is going to spend
   their life riding around parking lots. Thankfully this isn't true,
   but it does mean that many people have their bike fitted for flat
   land rather than climbing.

There are things you can try at home ***but I would recommend talking to a professional to get their expert advice on the correct fit for your style and terrain***.

You can:

- slide your seat forward in the rails (you may need to adjust the
  height also for your leg length)
- reconfigure the spacers on your stem (move the spacers above the stem
  and see if that has an effect)
- experiment with different stem lengths (this usually requires you to
  buy or borrow many stems to get the right one).

Many people spend thousands on a bike then scrimp on a $100 fitting.

Comment: It seems like this would be moving the handlebars down relative to the seat; but if I do too much of that I start having neck issues.

Answer (score 6):

You can work on a pedal stroke that applies pressure for a larger portion of the rotation of the pedals. That will reduce the peak force that is causing the wheel to lift.

Answer (score 1):

Because of a herniated disc in my lower back, I was forced to NOT PULL with my hands on steeps. Surprisingly, I found that by concentrating all of my energy below my belt, I could climb much better and faster. This was definitely a "lemonade from lemons" kind of discovery. Try this and see if it helps.